Simulate clients, where Server needs to call an endpoint on the client
I want to simulate X number of clients where the clients first makes a request to the server and the server then calls an endpoint running on the client.
The client consists of a python flask app, and some scripts that make a request to the server and then the server calls an endpoint on the client like say <client-addr:1069>/greetings
I need to simulate a scenario with 100 or maybe even 1000 clients, how to achieve this?
things I have looked at so far:

I see Apache Jmeter is an option but then each client must have its IP address, so ruled it out.
Creating VM's deploy the server on a VM, then create all the client VMs that share  same network, the issue here is my 8 core 16GB ram machine just may not be able to handle 100 VirtualBox instances
Docker containers

Docker containers have their IPs, is it possible I can configure routes or do some changes on the server so that the docker IP maps the host IP and some specific port on the host?
I mean all the server sees is 172.x.x.x:1069 it tries connecting to this address but internally it gets routed to something like 192.x.x.x:1000
Is something like above possible?
Also what are some other ways to simulate the test?
Edit:
The server is a Linux box, I have root access
I can make a specific fqdn map to an IP address by adding entries to /etc/hosts can anything similar be done to ensure <172.x.x.x> maps always to 192.x.x.x etc?

That setup is hard to make work reliably: if there's any sort of firewall or network address translation layer between the client and server, the server-calls-the-client path may not be reachable, and the fixed port number means you can't run concurrent clients.  (You mention Docker and it inserts a NAT layer that will cause problems.)  Can you redesign the application to use some other transport, maybe a websocket or a message queue?

I can get a local LAN, but the server application cant be redesigned, so creating a NAT on the server is not possible? Like 172.x.x.x:1069 -> map to 192.x.x.x:1000 etc?

Gievn I have my own LAN and can make changes on the Linux Server its not possible to route stuff to specific port numbers and IP's? Like for eg /etc/hosts can be modified to ensure a specific host/fqdn is mapped to an IP address anything along those lines

You in principle could build your own TCP router application, or adopt some sort of proxy tool (Nginx, socat), but what you're asking for isn't really a "normal" thing.  I'd prefer to fix the application protocol than to try to work around this design issue.

Its just for testing purposes, in the real world the client app will be running on each host and we will have a central server, we query the host only if the client give us some information, can you elaborate on how I can use nginx for this?

It totally depends on the network protocol being used under the hood, for example talking about Apache JMeter:

In case of server-sent events you can use a library which adds support of SSE to JMeter, see How to Load Test SSE Services with JMeter for more details.
In case of WebSockets there is JMeter WebSocket Samplers plugin

If you're using custom implementation of server-side events processing i.e. polling we'll need more details in order to come up with comprehensive suggestions

Is it possible to create nat/add route on the server (linux host) to force the packets of data to be resent to some other address+port number?
